# Show post in django admin page but don't on site

Tags: django

I'm creating simple blog and face with problem. I need to have separate type of posts in Django admin page which would be saved, but not showed on site. For example, when somebody suggest post, I want at first read it and after that publish, or when I'm writing a post and want go on after some time I need to save it.

blog/models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, default=1)
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    content = models.TextField(max_length = 50000)
    published = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return "/blog/%i/" % self.pk
```

blog/admin.py

```
class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = (
        ('Title',   {'fields' : ['title']}),
        ('Date',    {'fields' : ['pub_date'], 'classes' : ['collapse']}),
        ('Content', {'fields' : ['content']}),
    )
    list_display = ('title', 'pub_date')
    list_filter = ['pub_date']
    search_fields = ['title']

admin.site.register(Post, PostAdmin)
```

blog/views.py

```
class PostsListView(ListView):
    model = Post
```

Comment: In your view, you can limit the query so that only published posts are displayed, e.g `Post.object.filter(published=True)`. You haven't shown your view so it's hard to be more specific.

Comment: Yes, thank, and how make separate field for unpublished Posts?

Comment: I don't understand your question. You already have a boolean field `published` in your model.

Comment: In main django admin page i have field Posts and inside it all posts. How to make two field in one only published and in another only saved

Comment: There isn't an easy way to do that. Another approach is to set `list_filter = ['pub_date', 'published']`, then it will be easy to filter published/unpublished posts.

Comment: Thank you very mach. It's also will be good!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify your list view to only show published posts by overriding `get_queryset`.

```
class PostsListView(ListView):
    model = Post

    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(PostsListView, self).get_queryset().filter(published=True)
```

If you have a detail view, you should override `get_queryset` in the same way.

In your model admin, you can add `published` to `list_filter`. This makes it easy to filter published/unpublished posts.

```
class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...
    list_filter = ['pub_date', 'published']
```